# CherryPy form submission not recognizing date input as empty

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, cherrypy

I have a form where I request the user to submit a few different inputs. Then in the form action method, I specify that if any of the inputs are empty, redirect them to the form. This works for every input except the Date input. For some reason it never recognizes this as empty and submits the form anyways. I've tried it using type date and type text. If I delete the date input the form works fine. I've tried changing the name of the date input (which as expected doesn't fix it). It just seems fixed on that particular input.

In the below code I've commented out the db_func line, but with it commented or not, it passes through the if statement and on to the else if the date input is included.

```
@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def new_flight(self, msg="Add new flight"):
    return """<html><body>
    <form method="post" action="/add_flight">
    %(msg)s<br />
    Departure Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_from"/><br />
    Arrival Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_to"/><br />
    Date: <input type="text" name="date"/><br />
    Carrier: <input type="text" name="carrier"/><br />
    Flight No.: <input type="number" name="flight_no"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Flight" />
    </html></body>""" % locals()

@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def add_flight(self, airport_from=None, airport_to=None, date=None, carrier=None, flight_no=None):
    if airport_from is None or airport_to is None or date is None or carrier is None or flight_no is None:
        return self.new_flight("Please enter all information")
    else:
        #db_func.add_flight(cherrypy.request.login,airport_from,airport_to,date,carrier,flight_no)
        return self.home(msg="Your flight has been added.")
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get date to be treated like all the other inputs.

Comment: If you print the contents of date within the add_flight function, what do you get?

Comment: So I changed the input type to date, and if I print the contents I see that it is equal to '' when nothing is entered. I changed "date is None" to "date == ''". Now it returns "Please enter all information" if the date is blank, however if I enter a date and leave the other boxes blank it adds the flight. I'm not sure why date containing a value seems to trump the other boxes being blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should end your form tag...

```
@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def new_flight(self, msg="Add new flight"):
    return """<html><body>
    <form method="post" action="/add_flight">
    %(msg)s<br />
    Departure Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_from"/><br />
    Arrival Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_to"/><br />
    Date: <input type="text" name="date"/><br />
    Carrier: <input type="text" name="carrier"/><br />
    Flight No.: <input type="number" name="flight_no"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Flight" />
    </form></html></body>""" % locals()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I closed the form but I'm still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when a value is entered in the date box, it assigns some blank value to all the other boxes as well. This value isn't equal to '' but by changing the if conditions I was able to fix the problem. Instead of variable is None, I changed it to len(variable) < 1. I don't entirely understand why the issue is occurring but that fix got around the problem. My updated code is below.

```
@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def new_flight(self, msg="Add new flight"):
    return """<html><body>
    <form method="post" action="/add_flight">
    %(msg)s<br />
    Departure Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_from"/><br />
    Arrival Airport: <input type="text" name="airport_to"/><br />
    Date: <input type="date" name="date"/><br />
    Carrier: <input type="text" name="carrier"/><br />
    Flight No.: <input type="number" name="flight_no"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Flight" />
    </form></html></body>""" % locals()

@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def add_flight(self, airport_from=None, airport_to=None, date=None, carrier=None, flight_no=None):
    if len(airport_from) < 1 or len(airport_to) < 1 or date=='' or len(carrier) < 1 or len(flight_no) < 1:
        return self.new_flight("Please enter all information")
    else:
        db_func.add_flight(cherrypy.request.login,airport_from,airport_to,date,carrier,flight_no)
        return self.home(msg="Your flight has been added.")
```